# Maximal reductive subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}^e$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I cannot figure out how to prove the following statement, please help:

Let $e$ be a non-zero nilpotent element of $g$ and 
let $\mathfrak{s} =\{e, h, f\}$ be an $sl_2$-triple.

Then $\mathfrak{g}^\mathfrak{s}$ (the centralizer of $\mathfrak{s}$ in $\mathfrak{g}$) is a maximal
reductive subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}^e$.

Comment: Do you mean that $\mathfrak{s}=s$, and $\mathfrak{g}=g$?

Comment: This does not seem right (at least the way I read it). If the Lie algebra is just $sl_2$ with the usual basis then the centralizer of $s$ is trivial (being the center) while the centralizer of $e$ is $1$-dimensional. And since an abelian Lie algebra is reductive, the trivial subalgebra is not maximal reductive.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think, what is meant is that "The centraliser of the triple {e,h,f} in g is a maximal reductive subalgebra of $g_e$", see [Panyushev](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0007449704001101/1-s2.0-S0007449704001101-main.pdf?_tid=0f4e14b0-76fb-11e7-8c85-00000aacb35f&acdnat=1501620813_03a16c3fbfc50866eaa6a365332f9a71), page 860 for the context.

Comment: Thank a lot for help. Actually, I am reading the following paper                                                                \href{https://www.researchgate.net/publication/285850714_Classification_of_good_gradings_of_simple_Lie_algebras}{\textit{Classification of good gradings of simple Lie algebras}}, but I cannot find the reference book for the proof.